# paging on list not working

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, caml, paging

I want to do paging on sharepoint list. I have below code which is giving error.

```
var customlist;
var allItems;
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var listName = "MyList";
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

var spItems,
    position = null,
    nextPagingInfo,
    previousPagingInfo,
    pageIndex = 1, // default page index value 
    pageSize = 4, // default page size value 
    list,
    camlQuery,
    sortColumn = "Name";
debugger;
camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

camlQuery.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position);

camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View>" +
    "<ViewFields>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='Name'/>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='Email'>" +
    "</ViewFields>" +
    "<Query>" +
    "<OrderBy>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='" + sortColumn + "' Ascending='true' />" +
    "</OrderBy>" +
    "</Query>" +
    "<RowLimit>" + pageSize + "</RowLimit></View>");

spItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);


context.load(spItems, 'Include(Name,Age)');

context.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, function () {

        var enumerator = spItems.getEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {


            var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();

            var name = currentListItem.get_item('Name');

            var attachments = currentListItem.get_attachmentFiles();
            for (var j = 0; j < attachments.get_count() ; j++) {
                attachment = attachments.getItemAtIndex(j);
                console.log(attachment.get_serverRelativeUrl());


            }

        }
        div.html(innerHtml);

    }),
    Function.createDelegate(this, fail)
);

function fail() {
    debugger;
    alert(arguments[1].get_message());
}
```

Error is

> value doesnt fall within expected range

I think error is coming when i write this line

```
 camlQuery.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position);
```

Not sure what to pass in position variable. When I load page for first time what should I pass in position variable?

**Update1**

If i remove code

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View>" +
    "<ViewFields>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='Name'/>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='Email'/>" +
    "</ViewFields>" +
    "<Query>" +
    "<OrderBy>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='" + sortColumn + "' Ascending='true' />" +
    "</OrderBy>" +
    "</Query>" +
    "<RowLimit>" + pageSize + "</RowLimit></View>");
```

and pass hardcoded pagesize then i dont get error

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>3</RowLimit></View>');
```

**Update2**
Here is list view
[image]

Answer (score 1):

your original query has invalid xml, it should be

```
<FieldRef Name='Email' />
```

not

```
<FieldRef Name='Email'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declarations

```
var nextPagingInfo;
var previousPagingInfo;
var position;
```

Initial call you can make position null, so it starts from the begining

```
position = null;

//...CAML Query etc
context.load(spItems);
```

Now you can invoke the Query using `executeQueryAsync`. And use below `onSuccess`

```
function onSuccess() {   
    var listEnumerator = spItems.getEnumerator(); 
    var items = []; 
    var item; 

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) { 
        //Do your logic
    } 
    if (spItems.get_listItemCollectionPosition()) { 
        nextPagingInfo = spItems.get_listItemCollectionPosition().get_pagingInfo(); 
    } else { 
        nextPagingInfo = null; 
    }        
}
```

You can retrieve Next page items using

```
pageIndex++;
if (nextPagingInfo) { 
    position = new SP.ListItemCollectionPosition(); 
    position.set_pagingInfo(nextPagingInfo); 
}
```

You can retrieve Previous page items using

```
pageIndex = pageIndex - 1; 
position = new SP.ListItemCollectionPosition(); 
position.set_pagingInfo(previousPagingInfo);
```

Comment: i get error on line position.setpaginginfo(position) . error is Unable to get property 'set_pagingInfo' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Please see my updated question. It fails and go inside fail function. So i dont know what is wrong. I removed line position.setpaginginfo(position)

Comment: After line context.load(spItems, 'Include(Name,Age)');
it directly goes in function fail...

Comment: ---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
Failed to get items. Error:Value does not fall within the expected range.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: Tried but still same issue. It doesnt come inside first statement var enumerator = spItems.getEnumerator();. It directly goes to fail function

Comment: see my latest update in question

Comment: Thats what i am saying that if i remove viewfields and order by then it works. So what could be issue with using viewfields and order by

Comment: Make sure you are using proper field internal name. You can check it by opening the list settings page and hovering mouse over those fields.. and check querstring value of `Field`

Comment: please see aditional update on my question. check if view is correct. Did i understood u correctly? I have not created any additional view . i am just using default view

Comment: Read carefully.. I am asking you to check field internal names.. also I don't see a field with Display Name Age.

Comment: How to check field internal names. I am still very new to sharepoint.

Comment: this is what i got for field Name.. "http://doslaps104/_layouts/15/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7BB4AB8273%2D3E79%2D4652%2DBA1E%2D0F17475A6B1A%7D&Field=Name"